# Magento: Custom Selected Product in Category Page

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I work on Magento CE 1.8 and I got an issue. I want to add more field on Category Products tab in Manage Categories
The basic:

> [checkbox]  |  ID  |  Name  |  SKU  |  Price  |  Position

The goal:

> [checkbox]  |  ID  |  Name  |  SKU  |  Price  |  Best Seller  |  Position

And the "best seller" column is dropdown type with 2 value (Yes/No) 
I added it successfully. And now I want to edit the "Best Seller" value of a product like Yes->No or No->Yes by clicking on "Save Category" button. Please help me. Thanks alot

Comment: No one can help me? :(

Comment: Poor me :( No one knows it? :(